# In L4D2, how to print text in chat panel privately for yourself to see?

Tags: steam, left-4-dead-2

Typically if you want to write to the in-game chat panel, you use `say` and `say_team` to write to everyone and your team-only, respectively.

But what about writing to yourself? For example, if I set commands to remind me of options available (a menu system), how could I have this private to myself?

Alternatively, how can I display text the same way some modded servers do? (Like XPM, Buy, DLR servers, etc., only without the use of an actual modded server)

Here's an example of those in-game menus (see highlighted in red):
[image]

Also open to other alternative, like game instructor hints, but I have no idea how to access it from the console / keybinds.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I remember I use to admin a Counter-Strike server way back when (relevant because it uses the same engine) and we were able to do some coolish stuff with messages, and I believe it used a mod/add-on of sorts (I remember writing in the console, but not like sv_ or anything)

Comment: @Tas: Hmm, I'm unfamiliar to add-ons that extends the scripting support. So VPKs don't necessarily have to contain maps / models, it could just be a set of scripts that provides a mean to show something on-screen? (and if that's a possibility, do you know of any simple Getting Started tutorials on this type of development you could recommend?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those modded servers use [SourceMod](https://www.sourcemod.net/) to create new game elements and modify existing elements. That type of menu is a simple [VGUI](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VGUI_Documentation) element, not something created using the game's built-in chat system.

VGUI elements such as that menu are created by writing [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) code to several user-created files (both the game itself and SourceMod are created mostly/completely with C++). Therefore, to create a menu like this you'll need to know or at least understand how to code in C++. There are a lot of great tutorials out there on how to make custom menus. For example, one using [Valve's built-in VGUI system](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Custom_Menu_Screen) and one using [the simplified SourceMod VGUI system](https://wiki.alliedmods.net/Menu_API_(SourceMod)).

Now, I've been using SourceMod as an example because it provides simplicity, but since that is made to modify *servers* and you want a menu for *yourself* only, you'll have to rely on tutorials involving Valve's built-in system.

So to answer your question in the picture, you can't use just console commands and keybinds to create this kind of menu. You'll need those to *activate* your menu, but you can't *create* the menu with them.

Comment: Thanks, will read up on compiling SourceMod plugins. Hopefully menus are relatively straightforward to build. Quick sub-question though - do you know if multiple menus can co-exists on the screen or does some menus take priority / fight for which appears? Because, if I take the route of building one similar like the above modded servers (in the picture), I'm guessing in order not to flood the screen with menus there's gotta be some restrictions on which menus appears?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no restriction on that. You just have to be able to manage which are visible and taking the input at what time. Keep in mind though that to use a SM plugin you'll have to set up a server first.

Comment: Ok I think I'm missunderstanding. If I only want to use this for myself, would this be built-in C++ as well, just not compiled with SourceMod? (I basically want to show HLDJ sound names in an in-game menu rather than the console OR all/team-chat).

Comment: Worst comes to worst, I can try to write some file-watching app to update a small window floating outside the game screen (I usually play this in windowed-mode anyhow), since HLDJ updates a config file with the current directory it's loading the sounds from, at least I'm pretty sure.